# cannot bind to imported function. Error is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently having a problem importing a module and using it in react.  This has been asked and I've tried the answers I've read but nothing.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

In App.js I am importing this:

```
import { pullProductDetails } from './GetDetails';
```

In GetDetails.js I have this:

```
export default pullProductDetails = () => {
      this.setState({isLoading: true});
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_details/fetch/36')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        const quantityDetails = json.productQuanties.map((quantityDetail) => {
            quantityDetail.selected = false;
            quantityDetail.title = "Quantity";
        });
        this.setState(
          {
            quantityProduct: [...this.state.quantityProduct, ...json.productQuanties],
            isLoading: false,
          }, () => this.dropdownCounter()
        );
          });
    }
```

Then in app.js I bind it so I can use "this"

```
this.pullProductDetails = this.pullProductDetails.bind(this);
```

The error is that it can't bind this to undefined because pullProductDetails is undefined.

I've tried this also:

```
export const pullProductDetails = () => {}
```

None of the above work.  I need to call this.pullProductDetails from my App.js.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to omit the (this) at the right side of the assignment

```
this.pullProductDetails = pullProductDetails.bind(this);
```

Because the function you are binding is not a function of the current component. Also the definition of the pullProductDetails should not be an arrow function, as in arrow functions the context of this is always pointing to where the function is defined.

GetDetails.js:

```
export function pullProductDetails(){
  this.setState({isLoading: true});
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/product_details/fetch/36')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const quantityDetails = json.productQuanties.map((quantityDetail) => {
        quantityDetail.selected = false;
        quantityDetail.title = "Quantity";
    });
    this.setState(
      {
        quantityProduct: [...this.state.quantityProduct, ...json.productQuanties],
        isLoading: false,
      }, () => this.dropdownCounter()
    );
      });
}
```

In your main file:

```
import pullProductDetails from './GetDetails';
```

Then add the constructor function:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.pullProductDetails = pullProductDetails.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: It is giving this error: pullProductDetails is not defined @Bilal with the above suggestion.

Comment: Your import statement should have no brackets, since you are using (export default), since you are exporting as default, use: import pullProductDetails from './GetDetails';

Comment: Yes I had tried that because I thought the same but same error:  pullProductDetails is not defined @Bilal

Comment: I edited the answer to have full chuncks of code, this is working with me, can you try and give more details about where are you getting the error? is it while binding? or while calling this.pullProductDetails?

Comment: I'm using it with laravel and it's compiling it with webpack.  That's the only thing I can think of for it not working @Bilal

Comment: the error I see in the js file after compile is: exports.default = pullProductDetails = function pullProductDetails() {
@Bilal

Comment: I am not sure if it is while compiling it, but exports.default  function pullProductDetails() { .  also works for me

Comment: This works: export function pullProductDetails() { ...code... } @Bilal change that on your answer please and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Great that it worked for you, your edit is added to the answer